# Uniswap - Do you pay multiple fees when going through routes?

Tags: uniswap

If an X/USDT pair does not exist, we might want to trade between an intermediary coin such as ETH: so now we are trading X/ETH/USDT.

Does this incur two independent trades under the hood with separate trade fees, resulting in an overall trade fee that is double that of a direct trade?

Or is the trade fee the same regardless of how many intermediary steps in a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question, although not fully suited for this forum.

I would imagine that the route definition is simply a shortcut:

1. A -> B -> C in path is (trade wise) the same as executing A -> B and then B -> C
2. Saves in transaction fees, since it's in the same transaction. Also makes the thing atomic

Therefore you should pay all fees separately for each hop in the path. Because that's what the path does: it trades through the different pairs. It wouldn't be very fair if a pair doesn't get fees because it was participating in a path: from the pair's perspective the trade is exactly the same as a direct trade.